# Creating a composite type with "char"?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

[PostgreSQL has a type called `char` that's stored as an signed 1 byte int](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)

> The type `"char"` (note the quotes) is different from `char(1)` in that it only uses one byte of storage. It is internally used in the system catalogs as a simplistic enumeration type.

Can we create [composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) with `"char"`? I can create a table with it...

```
CREATE TABLE pixel ( r "char", g "char", b "char" );
```

Internally that creates a type which I can use elsewhere,

```
CREATE TABLE f ( mypixel pixel );
```

But, can I create a simple `TYPE` (no table) from it?

```
CREATE TYPE pixel ( r "char", g "char", b "char" );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""char""
LINE 1: CREATE TYPE pixel ( r "char", g "char", b "char" );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just the [missing keyword **`AS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html):

```
CREATE TYPE pixel AS (r "char", g "char", b "char");
```

The [data type `"char"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) is a non-standard type, primarily meant for internal purposes. But it's just another type - except for the peculiar spelling of the name including the double-quotes to disambiguate against `char`. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

Comment: Jesus Christ. they need to decide if `AS` and `TO` is optional or not and be consistent. Thanks =)

Comment: lack of `AS` changes the meaning here, and it's not really optional other places either, `SELECT asnumber AS as, source AS from FROM systems;`